# Get current Location Value under Regional language setting in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

Want to extract country name from the control panel->region and language->location current location value

i have tried following function of win32 
GetLocaleInfo(returns culture)
GetSystemDefaultLCID (returns language).
Also looked at the GetGeoInfo

but not able to extract the country name.
I hope i am clear with my question

Answer (score 2):

Its available by:

1. Get a `GEOID` by calling [`GetUserGeoID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `GEOCLASS_NATION`
2. Pass the `GEOID` to [`GetGeoInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) along with `GEO_FRIENDLYNAME` to fetch the string in the language specified in `LangId` (`GetUserDefaultLCID()` for the current)

Comment: Oddly, I can't get mine to return anything other than `GEOID_NOT_AVAILABLE` despite being set to UK :(

Comment: Weird works for me on 7, it returns whatever I set the control panel value too